# Prove a general version of Euler's formula

Tags: graph-theory

For a planar embedding of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges, $s$ faces and $c$ components, prove that: $n-m+s=1+c$

I have no real clue as to how to prove this, can someone help me?

Comment: Apply the one-component version of Euler's formula to each component separately, and then add them up.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify that for me? I am not sure what you mean by the 1-component version is? Do you mean $n-m+s=2$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I have been working on this but I am not sure how I am supposed to use this to prove that formula. :\

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: Good! Now, you can write it up, and post it as an answer. Then, after some time, you can accept your answer. This is encouraged here --- for one thing, it helps keeps the Unanswered list uncluttered.